# "Ещё" может быть общим второстепенным членом в ССП?

Tags: ссп, учебное-задание

"Еще трава полна прозрачных слез, и гром вдали гремит раскатом".

Почему "еще" не является общим членом? Разве нельзя отнести его ко второй части предложения?

Еще трава полна слез; еще гром гремит вдали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гроза прошла, и ветка белых роз  В окно мне дышит ароматом…
Еще трава полна прозрачных слез, И гром вдали гремит раскатом.

Наречие ***еще*** имеет значение "до сих пор" и в принципе может быть общим элементом, но **этот вопрос решается для конкретного текста, а не в общем виде.**

В данном случае автор рисует **такую картину:** гроза прошла, но в природе еще сохраняются ее  следы (свежее дыхание розы, мокрая трава, отдаленные раскаты грома).

**Эти явления однородны по смыслу,** поэтому при перечислении между ними желательно сделать паузу. Соответственно, автор не объединяет два последних предложения и ставит между ними запятую (относит ***еще*** только к одному предложению).